# buffer size changed

Tags: c++

I am doing a simple communication between sockets and here is my C++ code

```
while(1)
{
    string buffer = "23,45\n";
    const char* foo = buffer.c_str();
    cout << "size of buffer is " << sizeof(buffer)<<endl;
    send (s, foo, sizeof(buffer), 0);
}
```

weird thing is the fist iteration, the size of the buffer is 5 as expected, but since the second iteration and so on, the size dramatically jumped to 32. any idea why? Thank you very much. By the way, the added size comes from leading while spaces.

Comment: Why don't you just use `buffer.size()` as you should when using `string`?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` returns the size of the `buffer` object, which is not the same as the length of the string it contains.

Comment: Take a look here >> http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24922/

Comment: @Joachim I am new to C++, but doesn't **string buffer = "23,45\n";** already fix the length of the string object to be 6 like it would in Java? or the size of a string object in C++ is always 32? Thanks

Comment: @Clint, no in C++ `string` objects are not read-only, as they are in Java.  They can be resized, mutated, etc.  So the length of the string is only available at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size (in bytes) of the object.  It *doesn't* return the length of a container type.  You need to use `std::string::length()` or `std::string::size()` to determine the length of the string.

Comment: Thank you, couldn't have noticed the difference without the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the 5 of the first iteration: it must be coming from somewhere else. `sizeof(buffer)` is figured out at compile time - it is the size of `std::string`, so you should see 32 on every iteration.

If you are looking for the length of the string, use `buffer.size()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(buffer)` tells you the size of your `std::string` object, which has nothing to do with the number of characters you store in it (which by the way are 7 in your example, not 5).

Comment: The length of the string is `6`, as the terminating `'\0'` is not counted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There is a way to say it's 6, yes I give you this (for me, the *buffer* size is the size of the buffer, not the length of the string it holds). However, it is by no means 5.